# Overloading << operator for my own class why is this not working?

Tags: c++

I have a class and I wanna overload the << operator in it:

```
class Vector3
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
public:
    Vector3(int a, int b, int c) : x{a}, y{b}, z{c} {}
    Vector3 operator+(const Vector3& v);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ost, const Vector3& v);
    



};
```

But basically I want to be able to access the data members so here I did it with a friend function and just defined the function in a different file:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ost, const Vector3& v)
{
    return ost << '(' << v.x << ',' << v.y << ',' << v.z << ')';
}
```

But my question is how come when I don't use a friend function and just declare the function like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ost);
```

Then define it in a different file:

```
std::ostream& Vector3::operator<<(std::ostream& ost)
{
   return ost << '(' << x << ',' << y << ',' << z << ')';
}
```

When I try to actually use it

```
int main()
{
   Vector3 u(2,4,3);
   std::cout << u;

}
```

It just says:

```
> no operator matches these operands            operand types are:
> std::ostream << Vector3
```

But if I do `u.operator<<(std::cout);`
Then it works? But why? I thought that `std::cout << u;` is basically the same as `u.operator<<(std::cout)`;

Comment: You last sentence, you got it backward. `std::cout << u` is actually `cout.operator<<(u)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A a;
B b;
a << b;
```

The compiler looks for the member `operator<<` in `A` here, i.e. if `A::operator(B const&)` exists, the code snipped above uses it, but `B::operator<<(A&)` is not considered.

For your code this means the member operator required is `std::ostream::operator<<(Vector3 const&)` which you cannot add, since `std::ostream` is defined in the standard library. Your only choice here is a free function.

Comment: But the compiler also looks if there's a operator<<() function that takes (A a, B b) right? because it could be a member function or a free function right?

Answer (score 0):

Order matters. The overload you provided defines `u << cout` and not `cout << u`.